# Javascript,CSS not working in Google Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, browser

My Website is Not Working In Google Chrome Android. I tried IE In Android and it's working good but in google chrome it is not working.

My Website: http://obu.vn/Cart.aspx

Comment: This is not question for the SO.

Comment: Sorry. But can you help me resolve problem :( ?

Comment: Here you can do question about programming providing the code related with the problem that you have, so I suggest you to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and after edit your question  to be related with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable Javascript in Google Chrome on Mobile
2. Upgrade Version Google Chrome (Some of the functions in the current chrome version are not supported).
3. visit Tab anonymously in google chrome.